# Get a limited subquery result from a query that's already limited MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, limit

I know that the question name is kinda confusing, but what I want to do is (if possible)the following: In the following MYSQL query, I can get all phone numbers from the first 15 people, what I need is that with this query, if the person has more than 3 phone numbers, only return the first 3.

```
SELECT distinct(pp.PhoneNumber)
FROM person p
INNER JOIN personPhone pp ON p.personId = pp.personId
WHERE !ISNULL(pp.PhoneNumber)           
GROUP  BY p.PersonId, pp.PhoneNumber 
ORDER BY p.personId ASC LIMIT 0,15;
```

I have tried making a subquery on the `SELECT`, inside the `distinct` statement, but without any success

**EDIT:** Sorry I forgot to add the version of MySQL that I'm using, it is 5.7.24

Comment: What MySQL version? Window functions make this sort of query easier (MySQL-8.0/MariaDB-10.2+)

Comment: For readability I'd use `WHERE pp.PhoneNumber IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Please specify the MySQL version: 8.x or 5.x?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, `GROUP BY` is for aggregation.

Comment: How do you define "first three"?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of MySQL you have. If you have MySQL 8.x you can do:

```
select *
from (
  select
    personId, PhoneNumber, 
    row_number() over(partition by personId order by PhoneNumber) as rn
  from (
    SELECT distinct p.personId, pp.PhoneNumber
    FROM person p
    INNER JOIN personPhone pp ON p.personId = pp.personId
  ) x
) y
where rn <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get all the phone numbers per person and then use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to make sure you fetch only up to 3.

```
SELECT p.PersonId ID, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(pp.PhoneNumber)), ',', 3) Phone
FROM person p
INNER JOIN personPhone pp ON p.PersonId = pp.PersonId
WHERE pp.PhoneNumber IS NOT NULL        
GROUP  BY p.PersonId
ORDER BY p.PersonId ASC LIMIT 15;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not get all phone numbers from the first 15 people.  It gets 15 phone numbers, which is probably for fewer than 15 people.

To limit to 15 people, use a subquery.  Then you can limit to three numbers per person:

```
SELECT distinct(pp.PhoneNumber)
FROM (SELECT p.*
      FROM person p
      ORDER BY p.personId
      LIMIT 15
     ) p15 INNER JOIN
     personPhone pp
     ON p.personId = pp.personId
WHERE pp.PhoneNumber IS NOT NULL AND
      pp.PhoneNumber <= COALESCE( (SELECT pp2.PhoneNumber
                                   FROM personPhone pp2 
                                   WHERE pp2.PersonId = pp.PersonId
                                   ORDER BY pp2.PhoneNumber
                                   OFFSET 2 LIMIT 1
                                  ), pp.PhoneNumber)
```